# How to sanitize correctly this input?

Tags: php

I'm fairly new on PHP.

I'm trying to sanitize my input before UPDATE it on myqsql.

If my string is something with apostrophe, like  " I'm new on Php" it not works with this code

```
$description = $_POST['description'];

$description = htmlspecialchars($description);

$description = mysqli_real_escape_string($description);

$description = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $description));
```

It didn't work: my field in table result empty

If i use

```
$description = $_POST['description'];

$description = htmlspecialchars($description);

$description =  str_replace("'","\'", $description);

$description = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $description));
```

It works.

Why  `$description = mysqli_real_escape_string($description)` won't work ?

Comment: Adslashes. But dont do this, use a prepared statement and never worry about this again. Make a method if you want easy usage, you'll save tons of time not worrying about stuff like this.

Comment: For inserting into DB just `real_escape_string`. `htmlspecialchars` is for output to page, not saving into DB. `trim/preg_replace` is optional. Or forget for manually sanitizing SQL queries and use PDO.

Comment: _"Why $description = mysqli_real_escape_string($description) won't work?"_ - You're [using it wrong](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php). The first argument should be the connection. But as @Martijn said, use prepared statements with bound parameters instead of manually escaping the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont use functions like that, instead use prepared statements. Below a very minimalistic example, but it should give you something to build of off:

```
// Disclaimer: This is untested, but should give you a general direction:
function preparedQuery(string $sql, $paramtypes, $values){
    // Note: You need to some way to get the connection ($mysqli) in this 
    //       function. I suggest a Singleton DB class.
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param($paramtypes, ...$values);
    $stmt->execute();

    return $stmt;
}
```

And than you can use it:

```
$result = preparedQuery(
    "INSERT INTO tabel (name, email, age, date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, NOW())",
    'ssi', // s -> string, i -> integer 
    [$name, $email, $age]
);
```

You can fetch it using $result. You can use it in a while loop. I suggest you read up on prepared statements. It's a but tricky, but once you get the hang of it, very powerful en secure

Answer (score -2):

You need to use **htmlspecialchars** with **ENT_QUOTES**. This will convert double and single quotes.

```
<?php
$description = $_POST['description'];
$description = htmlspecialchars($description, ENT_QUOTES);
?>
```

While printing them you can just print it using ....

```
<?php
$row['description'];
?>
```

Comment: This doesnt answer the question. You answer is about displaying, but OP asks about storing it into a DB

Comment: For your kind info, the first variable: description will be use to store it into database.

Comment: a) Your answer isnt storing anything into the DB, which is the question. b) you answer outputs nothing as there is no echo (because you rollbacked by edit).